# Python: loop through list to concatenate different index items to different text files

Tags: python, concatenation

I am trying to use glob.glob to loop through my text files whilst at the same time looping through a list of words so I can concatenate a different word to each text file

The 4 text files and contents

```
File01.txt | File02.txt | File03.txt | File04.txt
bird       | cat        | dog        | fish
```

List of four words: ['ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR']

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import os

for name in glob.glob('file*'):
  print(name)

  num = 4
  lst = ['ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR']

  cnt = 0
  while num > 0:
    lst_loop = lst[cnt]
    print(lst_loop)
    cnt += 1
    num -= 1

    file = open('header', 'w')
    file.write(lst[0])
    file.close()

#    message = "cat header " + name + " > " lst[cnt] + name
#    command = os.popen(message)
#    print(command.read())
#    print(command.close())
```

I am aware that glob does not return a sequenced list but as it stands it returns the text files in the order of

```
file03.txt
file01.txt
file02.txt
file04.txt
```

So with this in mind the resulting files and file names should look like so:

```
TWOFile01.txt | THREEFile02.txt | ONEFile03.txt | FOURFile04.txt
TWO           | THREE           | ONE           | FOUR
bird          | cat             | dog           | fish
```

Comment: What is the question here

Comment: I want to use glob.glob to loop through my text files whilst also looping through my list so I can run my os command to concatenate a different word to each text file

Comment: So what is the question you are not able to loop through glob.glob? What is your expected output?

Comment: Your list and the number of files are always of the same length?

Comment: yes there always the same, I managed to get it working and have posted my answer, I was struggling to successfully loop through the glob.glob and list at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
import os

##list has newline character to allow for correct concatenation    
lst = ['ONE\n','TWO\n','THREE\n','FOUR\n']
cnt = 0

for name in glob.glob('file*'):

  lst_loop = lst[cnt]
  print(lst_loop)
  
  ##as I loop I write the contents to a text file called 'header'
  file = open('header', 'w')
  file.write(lst_loop)
  file.close()

  ##I now strip the new line character from the list for naming
  strip = lst_loop.strip("\n")

  ## and concatanate the contents of the header to the current file    
  message = "cat header " + name + " > " + strip + name
  command = os.popen(message)
  print(command.read())
  print(command.close())

  ##counter to loop through list of words
  cnt += 1
```

Comment: use `enumerate(sorted(glob.glob('file*')))` by doing so you can get rid of `cnt` variable, also the filenames will be sorted if you need that

Answer (score 0):

````
files = ["File01.txt", "File02.txt", "File03.txt", "File04.txt"]
words = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"]
for i in range(len(files)):
    with open(files[i], "a") as f:
        f.write(words[i])
```
````

Comment: I really need to use the OS command to achieve this as I also need to alter my example once I get it working, but have got in trouble in the past for asking complicated questions, so this is as simple as I can make it so not to get another question deleted

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```py
from glob import iglob

words = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"]

for word, f in zip(words, sorted(iglob("file*.txt"))):
    with open(f), open(word + f.capitalize(), "w+") as fp, new:
        new.write("\n".join([word, fp.read()]))
```

NOTE: zip will not throw an error if length mismatch between `words` and files found with glob pattern. It will use the shortest iterable an then break the loop.

`sorted(iglob("file*.txt"))` should get the order correct for you

`open(word + f.capitalize(), "w+")` create a new file or overwrite if it exist

`with` statement is used to handle file close even if you get an error during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
    
fls=glob.glob("*.txt") #match all text files
#shorting the list given by glob in ascending order
fls = sorted(fls) #['File01.txt', 'File02.txt', 'File03.txt', 'File04.txt']

lst = ['ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR']

c = 0
# counter variable c will help us to loop the list 'lst'
for fl in fls:
    with open(fl, 'r+') as f: #open files and read/write mode
        k = f.read().splitlines() #each line into list
        s = lst[c] + "\n" + k[0] #using counter c and variable k will be a list 
        f.seek(0) #move file pointer to starting of file
        f.truncate() #remove everything from starting
        f.write(s) #write the new string 's'
        c = c + 1 #change the counter value to next index in list 'lst'
```